# Is Microsoft Video indexer expected to detect text shown while presenting a document in a meeting?

Tags: azure, azure-video-indexer

We are exploring Microsoft Indexer for compliance and uploaded a video of a user sharing a spreadsheet with creditcard numbers expecting the Azure service to perform OCR for the  numbers.

This is what i read:"Visual text recognition (OCR): Extracts text that's visually displayed in the video." here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/video-indexer/video-indexer-overview

Here is a link to the video :
https://www.videoindexer.ai/accounts/9cc5a4d4-7d5a-4e55-bf8c-1d4d9d885c3a/videos/a6ba99525f/?location=Trial

This did not happen

Any idea what type of text can be detected ?

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the insight tab, and go down to you will find in bold "3 Named entities" one of them is MasterCard, click on it, it will show the exact screen where it appeared.